# Will pyqt5 connected with MySQL work on other computers without MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

I am building a GUI software using `PyQt5` and want to connect it with `MySQL` to store the data.

In my computer, it will work fine, but what if I transfer this software to other computer who doesn't have `MySQL`, and if it has, then it will not have the same *password* as I will add in my code (using `MySQL-connector`)a password which I know to be used to connect my software to MySQL on my PC.

My question is, how to handle this problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your database to be installed with your application and NOT shared by different users using your application, then using SQLite is a better choice than MySQL. SQLite by default uses a file that you can bundle with your app. That file contains all the database tables including the connection username/password.